# How to fadeIn elements as they reach the containers scrollTop in JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to `fadeIn()` all of my elements as the user scrolls down the page. When the `scrollTop()` of the document reaches the `scrollTop()` of the element, the element should show.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(this).scroll(function() {
    let pos = $(this).scrollTop();
    $('.full-height').each(function() {
      if (pos > $(this).scrollTop()) {
        $(this).closest('inner').fadeIn();
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```css
.full-height {
  height: 100vh;
}

.flex-center {
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.position-ref {
  position: relative;
}

.inner {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="flex-center position-ref full-height">
  <div class='inner'>
    Foo
  </div>
</div>
<div class="flex-center position-ref full-height">
  <div class='inner'>
    Bar
  </div>
</div>
```

However, my current code is not working at all. Since I have multiple containers, I tried to use the `each()` method within these multiple containers to individually check their `scrollTop()`.

How can I display my inner elements when the scroll bar hits the top of the element?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few issues.

- Bind to window if you are scrolling the main page
- Get the `offset().top` to get how far down the page an element is
- `.inner` is a child of the `.full-height`, not a parent, so use `find()`
- Your `inner` selector was incorrect.  Use `.inner` for classes

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    let pos = $(this).scrollTop();
    $('.full-height').each(function() {
      if (pos > $(this).offset().top) {
        $(this).find('.inner').fadeIn();
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```css
.full-height {
  height: 100vh;
}

.flex-center {
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.position-ref {
  position: relative;
}

.inner {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="flex-center position-ref full-height">
  <div class='inner'>
    Foo
  </div>
</div>
<div class="flex-center position-ref full-height">
  <div class='inner'>
    Bar
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I appreciate the knowledge on doing this too!

Comment: Well-written answer. +1